# Vuejs and Jquery (and firefox)

Tags: jquery, firefox, vuejs2

I have problem with vuejs and jquery(and maybe with firefox), here the things:

1. I create a vuejs method and put this method to nexttick.
2. I loading data by Ajax, and then bind response to vuejs object.
3. I am running v-for to create the datatable(it's just simple HTML table tag with ID).
4. Here most mystical: after this I am trying to do some manipulation with datatable(searching by id), like binding some classes for example, or using fade animation and other stuff, so nothing happen.

If I run the same method by clicking, or using another browser like opera, chrome, ie everything works fine.

If I will run this code in the method:
`console.log($('#datatable').length)`
and will call this method using nexttick - firefox will say 0! Other browsers will say 1(based on size or existing I guess). And if I will run this method by clicking(or others events, like keyup, mousedown, etc) firefox also display 1!

Comment: Need to see some code.

Comment: Oh, i have lot of code. I will try past code here

Comment: Please don't dump lots of code here; reduce the problem to a [mcve] and post that.  But, yes, without code this question is difficult to answer (though at a guess I'd bet it's async-code-related, and that you're trying to manipulate the data before it's returned from the server.)

Comment: Think I solved this problem. Well, I am not sure, but Firefox have problem with vuejs v-if directive. Also, I found one workaround - need add some "setTimeout" or replace v-if to vuejs components maybe. Thanks for your help guys!